# SSO Authorization: Is there any other way to store roles and permissions other than JWT

Tags: single-sign-on

Right now, we are passing claims(like an instance which holds roles and permissions) in JWT Token. But,the disadvantages like 
1) The list of access points can encoded into the JWT but they will increase it's size.

2)This token will be sent with every request they will be sanctioned for the life of the access token (currently 30 minutes) so back end changes will not be reflected until this token expires and a new one is generated. A similar scenario is when tokens are revoked, existing tokens will still be valid for their lifetime and will honor the access points encoded within

3)These access points may pose a security risk because a JWT token can be decoded with readily accessible tools e.g. https://jwt.io/ 
The token is signed so tampering can be detected but it exposes information that may be used maliciously

Can anyone help whether there are any other ways to acces roles and permissions to handle authorization apart from claims through JWT